# Multilabel Text Classification using Hugging Face Models for TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, text-classification, huggingface

Trying to understand example of use  Hugging Face Model for Multilabel Text Classification using Tenroflow from https://www.daniweb.com/programming/computer-science/tutorials/539042/multilabel-text-classification-using-hugging-face-models-for-tensorflow

Please, help to understand using BinaryCrossentropy as loss and metrics while have 6-classes classification. Doesn't one should use CategoricalCrossentropy instead?

Comment: For multi-label task, loss funciton binary cross entropy is usually chosen. If it were mult-class, then may be categorical-ce / sparse-categorical-ce.

Comment: @Innat thanks a lot!!! I've really "read" that example as multi-class!! Thank you )